# What is the difference between dict[new_key] = [dict[key], new_value] and x = dict[key] + [new_value]?

Tags: python, list

I was reading the Python Patterns essay on graph implementations, and came across the section that discusses the optimal implementation of finding the shortest path.  The article is [here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/).

I couldn't understand the difference between the two assignments to `dist[next]`; the latter is quadratic in runtime, but the former is linear?

Linear runtime:

```
# Code by Eryk Kopczyński 
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end):
    dist = {start: [start]}
    q = deque(start)
    while len(q):
        at = q.popleft()
        for next in graph[at]:
            if next not in dist:
                dist[next] = [dist[at], next]  # this line
                q.append(next)
    return dist.get(end)
```

Quadratic runtime:

```
# Code by Eryk Kopczyński 
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end):
    dist = {start: [start]}
    q = deque(start)
    while len(q):
        at = q.popleft()
        for next in graph[at]:
            if next not in dist:
                dist[next] = dist[at] + [next]  # this line
                q.append(next)
    return dist.get(end)
```

Can someone please explain what the difference is between these two assignments?

Comment: Adding lists is expensive since you need to copy over all the elements.

Comment: The first one looks like a linked list.

Comment: `[dist[at], next]` is a list with two elements - no matter what the previous value of anything was.  `dist[at] + [next]` has one more element than `dist[at]` had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` `]` bracket notation is used for both
subscript de-reference
and for constructing lists.

You asked about these expressions:

```
            dist[next] = [dist[at], next]

            dist[next] = dist[at] + [next]
```

Let's ignore the LHS left hand side of the assignment, as
it is simply storing a dict mapping.
Rather than `dist[next] = ...`
it could as easily have been `x = ...`
followed by `dist[next] = x`.

Similarly, in the RHS let's ignore the `dist[at]`.
We easily could have set a temp var beforehand: `y = dist[at]`, and then use `y` in the expression.

---

Ok, with square bracket notation out of the way, let's focus on the algorithmic complexity of constructing `[y, next]` and `y + [next]` expressions, where `y` is a list.

We can compute the first expression in O(1) constant time.
We simply allocate a short list and fill its
first two elements with pointers to the `y` and to the `next` objects.

The second list expression, `y + [next]`, requires scanning each element of `y` and copying it into a new temporary result,
then finally appending a `next` pointer to that result.
This has O(n) linear cost, if `y` is of length `n`.

**Explanation**

Why was that extra work necessary?
Well suppose an element of `y` is subsequently mutated, changed to a new value.
The first expression is fine with that, it will reflect the new value,
since the programmer asked to store a pointer in the list, a reference to what `y` was pointing at.

OTOH the second expression won't preserve that relationship, it is looking just at the *values* on either side of the `+` plus sign.
Imagine that we store that "big list" result and then mutate `y`.
There will be no effect on the big list, which is as it should be.